# passing index to props in react native

Tags: react-native

I have trouble passing these index to my component, i'm trying to pass the icon and the description. What should i call in the props to grab all the items in index

this is my index.js

```js
    
    export const img =
{      
    itemStatus: {
        "Open": { name: 'open-book', type: 'entypo', color: '#ffb732', desc:'New Attribut, New Attention'},
        "Approved": { name: 'checklist', type: 'octicon', color: '#3CB371', desc:'Approved by SPV/MNG' },
        "Escalated": { name: 'mail-forward', type: 'font-awesome', color: '#ffb732', desc:'Escalated to SPV/MNG' },
        "Deliver Partial": { name: 'arrange-send-to-back', type: 'material-community', color: '#8B4513', desc:'Some items in a DO have not arrived/was faulty' },
        "Deliver": { name: 'truck-fast', type: 'material-community', color: '#8B4513', desc:'On delivery' },
        }
```

and my component

```js
<IconModal visible={this.state.currentStatus !== null} close={this.handleDismissModal} status={this.state.currentStatus} 
                       desc={img.itemStatus.desc}
                       icon={}
                       
                       />
```

Comment: your `img.itemStatus` does not have any `desc` property, how are you accessing `img.itemStatus.desc`

Comment: what do you mean? it has in every itemstatus

Comment: Yeah but you can't access it by `img.itemStatus.desc`, you have to do `img.itemStatus.Open.desc` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong `key` here `desc={img.itemStatus.desc}` in this line,

```
<IconModal visible={this.state.currentStatus !== null} close={this.handleDismissModal} status={this.state.currentStatus} desc={img.itemStatus.desc} icon={} />
```

If you want to access `desc` from your object you can do this,

```
desc = {Img.itemStatus.Open.desc}   // to get desc from Open item
Or
desc = {Img.itemStatus.Approved.desc} // to get desc from Approved item
Or
desc = {Img.itemStatus.Escalated.desc} // to get desc from Escalated item
Or
desc = {Img.itemStatus.Deliver.desc} // to get desc from Deliver item
```

**Note:** In your `img` object you have this,

```
'Deliver Partial': {
      name: 'arrange-send-to-back',
      type: 'material-community',
      color: '#8B4513',
      desc: 'Some items in a DO have not arrived/was faulty',
    }
```

Don't write object key as `'Deliver Partial'` you won't be able to access it, just change it to,

```
Deliver_Partial: {
      name: 'arrange-send-to-back',
      type: 'material-community',
      color: '#8B4513',
      desc: 'Some items in a DO have not arrived/was faulty',
    }
```

[Simplified demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-yq7kc?fontsize=14) to access `desc` from each key of `img` object

Comment: well the name, type, color is the icon its from react native elements, i'm sorry if i ask too much i'm still new

Comment: Post your `IconModal` component.

Comment: i just post it you can check

Comment: same way you can pass icons like `icon = {Img.itemStatus.Open.name}`

Comment: Also you can pass type and color like `type= {Img.itemStatus.Open.type}` & `color= {Img.itemStatus.Open.color}` and access the same in your IconModal component as `props.type` & `props.color`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196236/discussion-between-billy-ronaldo-chandra-and-ravibagul91).

Comment: When you pass `icon = {Img.itemStatus.Open.name}` and usage in your `IconModal` component is ` <Icon name={props.icon} />`

Comment: sorry for the late reply , it totally works thankyou